# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis..An exception occurred processing JSP page at line 29

Tags: sql, oracle

**At line 29 it says ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
I have marked the line with the no 29**
I am unable to understand where the paranthesis is missing

```
<%
    String r = request.getParameter("t1");
    String n = request.getParameter("t2");
    String d = request.getParameter("t3");
    String b = request.getParameter("t4");
    String y = request.getParameter("t5");
    String c = request.getParameter("t6");
    String bg = request.getParameter("t7");
    long cno=Long.parseLong(c);
    String x="N.A";
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "aman", "123456");
    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("update icard2 set rollno=(?=r),name=(?),dob=(?),branch=(?),year=(?),contact=(?),bloodgroup=(?),photofile=(?),collname=(?),colllogo=(?) where rollno=r");
    ps.setString(1,r);
    ps.setString(2,n);
    ps.setString(3,d);
    ps.setString(4,b);
    ps.setString(5,y);
    ps.setLong(6,cno);
    ps.setString(7,bg);
    ps.setString(8,x);
    ps.setString(9,x);
    ps.setString(10,x);

**29**  ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();
    cn.close();
    out.println("Record Updated");
%>
```

Comment: Never, ever put SQL code into a JSP (and don't create a connection each time the JSP is called.

Comment: `set rollno=(?=r)` is invalid. And you don't need all those parentheses around the question marks

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your SQL statement.  This does not look like valid SQL:

```
set rollno=(?=r)
```